# Terraform apply second time on Azure yaml pipeline fails | not storing state files in blob storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I'm deploying Azure blob storage using Terraform in the Azure YAML pipeline.

The deployment from scratch works and deploys a number of resources including resource groups and blob storage. However, the second deployment fails, saying the resource group already exists. The terraform plan(on the second try) also shows old resources to create, so it is supposed to fail at terraform apply. Upon checking, it's not storing my terraform state files(after the first deploy) in Azure blob/container.

Pipeline Configuration:

```
steps:
- bash: |
    cd ./terraform
    terraform -version
    terraform init \
      -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(tfcicd-blob-account-name-kv)" \
      -backend-config="access_key=$(tfcicd-blob-key-kv)" \
      -backend-config="container_name=$(terraformStateContainer)" \
      -backend-config="key=$(terraformStateFile)"
  displayName: Terraform Init

- bash: |
    cd ./terraform
    terraform plan \
      -var-file=$(terraformVarFile) \
      -out $(terraformPlanFile)
  displayName: Terraform Plan
  env:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID:        $(tfcicd-subscription-id-kv)
    ARM_CLIENT_ID:              $(tfcicd-sp-clientid-kv)
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET:          $(tfcicd-client-secret-kv)
    ARM_TENANT_ID:              $(tfcicd-sp-tenantid-kv)

- bash: |
    cd ./terraform
    terraform apply -auto-approve $(terraformPlanFile)
  displayName: Terraform Apply
  env:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID:        $(tfcicd-subscription-id-kv)
    ARM_CLIENT_ID:              $(tfcicd-sp-clientid-kv)
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET:          $(tfcicd-client-secret-kv)
    ARM_TENANT_ID:              $(tfcicd-sp-tenantid-kv)
```

Terraform configs
I have a backend.tf file in the terraform/backend directory.

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not storing the state files in the blob storage and not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any lead would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The backend.tf file must contain all the values of your tfstate file

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "storageaccountrg"
    storage_account_name = "storageaccountname"
    container_name       = "containername"
    key                  = "statefilename.tfstate"
  }
}
```

and this my task for Init.

```
- task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'Terraform Init'
            env:
              ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
              ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
              ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
              ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                terraform init \
                  -backend-config="access_key=$(stgaccount-key1)"
              workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(FILE_PATH)"
```

Comment: Thanks Dilly, The problem with this is I can't use variables in the backend.tf file to differentiate multi-environment deployment and store environment-specific tfstate files to respective blog storage. I am new to terraform and can't figure out how to leverage multi-env deployment with terraform.

Comment: Please explore Variable Groups. There you can create variable groups for each environment and based on branch trigger condition select respective variable group and read variables.